# Changing the version of a transitive dependency in maven pom.xml

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, pom.xml, dependency-management

I've been trying to override a transitive dependency version in one of my projects. I found the following sample project on github to experiment on ( https://github.com/Richou/swagger-codegen-maven-plugin). The parent pom of this project contains a dependency for swagger-codegen. Swagger-codegen in turn has a dependency called slf4j-ext whose version is 1.6.3. I want to upgrade/override the version of slf4j-ext to 1.7.30 from the parent pom. I tried adding the required slf4j-version inside the property tag in the parent pom but it didn't work when I checked the maven dependency tree. What is the correct method to do it?

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-codegen</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<properties>
    <slf4j-version>1.7.30</slf4j-version>
    <java.version>1.7</java.version>
</properties>
```

Comment: is there any reason why the property override is not working?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add the slf4j-ext with the version you want in the dependencyManagement section of your parent pom.

```xml
<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-ext</artifactId>
      <version>${slf4j-version}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "sometimes it may not be enough" ?  `<dependencyManagement>` overrides transitive dependencies.

Comment: You're right, I edited my answer to remove this part.

Comment: <dependencyManagement> works but could anyone tell me why overriding the version inside <properties> in parent pom is not working? I want to get a better understanding of how pom works.

Comment: Because the properties you define in your pom do not apply to your dependencies, it only apply to your pom and sub-modules. In other word it is not possible to override a property defined in a dependency.